# Inputting values into few arrays

Tags: java

I have to input values into array by using only one dimenisional array. In one array there is range check for weight which later must be print. However, for some reason the if condition stay the same for all printed input:

Test data :
Gender: Female
Name:   Giselle
Height:  165
Weight:   53

Gender: Male
Name:   Adam
Height: 178
Weight  74

Incorrect output:

Female Giselle 170 53 "Your weight is normal"
Male Adam  178 74 "Your weight is normal"

it Should output:
Female Giselle 170 53 "Your weight is normal"
Male Adam  178 74 "You're obese"

I realize that program at the moment doesnt make sense but this are my requirements, which I try to solve for the last 10 hours. I'm not askin for the code but rather suggestion how should solve this. Thanks

```
final int PGENDER = 2, PNAME = 2, PWEIGHT = 2, PHEIGHT = 2;


    String weightDesc = null;


    String [] gender = new String[PGENDER],
              name = new String[PNAME],
              height= new String[PHEIGHT];

    int [] weight  = new int[PWEIGHT];


    int weightScale = 0;


    for( int i=0; i < gender.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your gender");
        gender[i] = s.nextLine();

    }



    for(int i=0; i < name.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        name[i] = s.nextLine();
    }



    for( int i=0; i < height.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your height");
        height[i] = s.nextLine();
    }



    for(int i=0; i< weight.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your weight");
        weight[i] = s.nextInt();

        weightScale = weight[i];

        if (weightScale <= 55){
            weightDesc = "Your weight is normal";
            }
        else if ( weightScale > 56 && weightScale < 64){
            weightDesc = "You're over weight";
            }
        else if (weightScale > 65 && weightScale < 72){
            weightDesc = "You're obese";
            }

        }

    for(int i = 0; i< gender.length;i++) {

        System.out.println(gender[i] + " "+ name[i]+ " " + height[i] + "" + weight[i]+ " " + weightDesc);
    }
```

Comment: You say it should output "You're obese" for 74 but it will only print that if `weightScale < 72`

Answer (score 0):

You only have one `weightDesc` variable, so in your loop your are updating the same variable.

Consider having a array of `weightDesc` like your other variables.

**But**

In reality that way that you are doing is not good, better to design a class that contains all of your variables and then have an array/list of these Objects.

**Also**

Why duplicate these values

```
final int PGENDER = 2, PNAME = 2, PWEIGHT = 2, PHEIGHT = 2;
```

it just makes your code more difficult to follow, why not

```
final int arraySize = 2;
```

**suggested way**

```
for( int i=0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter your gender");
    String gender = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your height");
    String height = s.nextLine();

   MyClass obj = new MyClass (gender, name, height);
   myArr [i] = obj;

}

// now loop and print
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions about class but I cant create any objects. Only storing them like that in arrays.